# Is there a switch that I can stop writing to log file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just want to see some debug messages on the screen.
But the debug message is a little heavy to write to log files.   It makes my ros can't run smoothly.

So, I wonder know is there a command that I can stop all log file but have no affect on the screen output.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272782/is-there-a-switch-that-i-can-stop-writing-to-log-file-?/) by [Cabbage](https://answers.ros.org/users/32159/cabbage/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably won't help in the long run, but you can disable rosout in roscore.xml, see [10068](https://answers.ros.org/question/10068/roslaunch-without-rosout/)

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0